# Going to the zoomed view of a particular 3Dbuilding using an URL in cesium API

Tags: 3d, zoom, cesium, url

I have a cesium application which shows 3d buildings for an area. What I want is if I give some URL it should go to the zoomed view of a particular building. Say for ex: if I give http://localhost:8383/Cesium_3D_Buildings/Apps/Sandcastle/gallery/GeoJSON_Hubli_3D.html/**kimscentrallibrary** it should go to the Kims central library building with the zoomed view. I know it can be done somehow by **fly to** but is is possible using a URL in cesium API?

Comment: I can get the name of each building by entities[x].properties.name. And if the name given in URL matches the entities.properties.name it should go to viewer.flyTo(entities[x]). I don't have any idea in using queryToObject for this purpose.